# A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, dll

I created new Windows Phone 7.1 project in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I have Windows Phone 8 SDK (and I am using Windows 8.1 Pro). I am trying to add AdMob.dll (from Google) which I downloaded today (version 6.5.13). When I try to add this dll to the project, I get an error: "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project".

Common solution for this error is to unblock the file, but I don't have "Unblock" button in Windows Explorer when I go to dll properties. I tried to unblock the dll (and the entire zip) using powershell command "Unblock-File". I tried using streams.exe to ublock the entire unzipped folder that I downloaded form Google, so I would say that this dll isn't blocked, but I still cannot add it to my solution.

Is this version of AdMob.dll incompatible with my VisualStudio/Windows/solution or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admob 6.5.13 targets Windows Phone 8 and thus a higher version of the Core Framework, at least the version on the current download page. I suspect you'll need to find a much older version that was compiled against Phone 7, but I do now know if that version would still be supported by google.